# PostgreSQL Function - Return a single row from multiple queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I would like to write a Postgres function which takes various stats from other tables and combines the results into a single row.

e.g.

```
select count(*) as acount from tableA
select count(*) as bcount from tableB
select count(*) as ccount from tableC
```

returning

```
acount, bcount, ccount   as a single record
```

Obviously the "count" functions listed above are a lot more complex than that, and may even be different amounts of counts for each table.

So ideally is it possible to store them as variables and then build a record from the variables ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use cross join

```
select * from
(select count(*) as acount from tableA) as a
,(select count(*) as bcount from tableB) as b
,(select count(*) as ccount from tableC) as c
```

Comment: Actually, this seems faster and allows for multiple aggregates on each subquery. Yay !

Comment: you can use a up-to-date version  of cross join as well, happy to help _select * from
(select count(*) as acount from tableA) as a
cross join (select count(*) as bcount from tableB) as b
cross join (select count(*) as ccount from tableC) as c_

Answer (score 4):

No need for variables, you can just combine everything into one select statement with subqueries:

```
select
(select count(*) from tableA) as acount,
(select count(*) from tableB) as bcount,
(select count(*)  from tableC) as ccount;
```

Comment: Good, and useable but doesn't like if I make one of them have 2 cols like count(*), sum(items) .     Anyway to cater for that ?

Comment: @blissweb just add another select for the sum.

Comment: For performance hack, discovered this works ...   CONCAT(CAST(sum(noitems) AS VARCHAR(10)) , '-' , CAST(count(*) AS VARCHAR(10)))    Maybe someone knows if that will save resources over 2 SELECTS.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a new type that consist of 3 bigint type.

```
CREATE TYPE mutli_count AS (
    _countt1 bigINT,
    _countt2 bigint,
    _countt3 bigINT
);

select( 
    (select count(*) from country),
    (select count(*) from states),
    (select count(*) from cities))::mutli_count;
```